# How to make a 2D array thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, multidimensional-array, synchronization, thread-safety

So I have a 2D array which will have moving Objects from one index to another index eg from index A - B. During the move no other Objects can be stored inside A or B.

Originally I was thinking to use ReentrantLocks but i'm apparently not allowed to. I was also worried about a performance bottleneck if every square had their own Lock.

Then I though about using AtomicReferences but it didn't seem to give me the functionality I was hoping for as I need a way to check to see if either of the indexes of the array are occupied.

One way I thought of would be to use a mutex.
But I got a bit confused on how I could use this mutex to lock specific indexes of an Array at a time.
If I was to use a mutex, this was how I was thinking.

So in this example I have an array of Objects, where each object will have their own synchronized set method. The object will be shown below.

```java
public class ExampleObject {
    private Object monitor = new Object();
    private StoredObject storedObject;

    public void set(StoredObject inStoredObject) {
        boolean setStatus = false;
        synchronized (mutex) {
            if (storedObject == null) {
                storedObject = inStoredObject;
                setStatus = true;
            }
        }
        return setStatus;
    }

    public StoredObject get() {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return storedObject;
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            storedObject = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I had to check if the StoredObject is null as I don't want the StoredObject to be set if one already exists.
So I added the clear method as my idea was that if a StoredObject is moving from Index A -> B. It could leave a Copy of itself inside A and remove itself from A when it is successfully inside B (as transmission isn't instantaneous and takes 500 ms).

I am allowed to use Blocking Queues, monitors and volatile.

Comment: From what I understand, you are having the same array data shared between two process (maybe on different machines) and want to do atomic operations on that array?

Comment: What about put/delete operations, those aren't having the same transmission delay (with a smaller time needed for transmission) ?

Comment: Yeah ill have upwards of 10 threads moving their objects inside the array

Comment: The threads need to wait for the operation to be completed? What about the transmissions, are they unidirectional (like in a primary-backup setup)?

Comment: If I had an Array Like this:
[A, B] [C, D] - but imagine its a 2D array.

If an Object starts at position A and moves to B. Once the move has completed, it could move back to A if something else hasn't taken it's position in the meantime.